# JMeter Non-GUI-Mode one logfile for every sampler

Tags: jmeter

What i want to do is to run JMeter in non-GUI mode and get a logfile for every single sampler, not just the entire testcase. Is there a way to accomplish that?

I'm using v3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [Beanshell Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Listener) at end of your Thread Group and put this script:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.net.URLDecoder;

import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

String samplerNumber = "${__threadNum}";
String samplerName = "${__samplerName()}";

if(sampleEvent.getResult() instanceof org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampleResult) {
    String request = (sampleEvent.getResult().getSamplerData());
    String response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();

    f = new FileOutputStream("/home/username/logs/myJMeterLog.log", true);
    p = new PrintStream(f); 

//EDIT:
    p.println("Thread: " + samplerNumber + ", sampler name: " + samplerName + ", system time: " + new Date() +"\nREQUEST: " + java.net.URLDecoder.decode(request, "UTF-8") + "\nRESPONSE: " + response + "\n\n");

    p.close();
    f.close();
}
```

You can modify it to meet your requirements. It will log every HTTP request data to given log file. You can also name log file as some thread specific variable (e.g. username) to have separate logs for each thread. Hope this helps...

Another answer (for this add one Counter - config element to HTTP sampler and put counter as reference name):

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.net.URLDecoder;

import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

String samplerName = "${__samplerName()}";

if(sampleEvent.getResult() instanceof org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampleResult) {


    f = new FileOutputStream("/home/username/logs/" + samplerName +.log", true);
    p = new PrintStream(f); 

    p.println("Request: " + java.net.URLDecoder.decode(request, "UTF-8") + ", sample time: " + prev.getTime() + ", sample count: " + String.valueOf(vars.get("counter")));

    p.close();
    f.close();
}
```

Comment: Okay, I'm literally a retard when it comes to code. Could you perhaps make a little example for what I'm trying to achieve. Say i have a Http-Sampler that goes on website1 and another sampler for Website2. Now I want to get a logfile "website1.jtl" for only those requests made towards website1, and so on.

Comment: In FileOutputStream you could change `"FileOutputStream("/home/username/logs/" + samplerName + ".log", true)`. I think you would get log for each sampler by doing so.

Comment: Kay, that's working so far! But the logs are empty ._.
ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.text.ParseException; import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; import java. . . . '' : Error in method invocation: Static method format( java.lang.String ) not found in class'java.lang.String'

Comment: OK, I have replaced String.format() which is static method... Try now.

Comment: Kay, we're getting closer :D log's getting filled now, but with the wrong data. It logs the entire html Code in there. I'd be happy if i could get the sampletime

Comment: Only sample time?

Comment: let's say Sample-time, and Sample counter. For example Sample: 1 Request: something.com, SampleTime: 100ms

Comment: I have edited answer with another script. You will need counter on HTTP Request...

Comment: I can't express how much i appreciate that. I'd say that I love you. I love my mom, what i feel for you is far beyond that! :P

Comment: out of curiosity, is there a way to save that as a working .jtl file instead of a .log file?

Comment: You could change .log to .jtl I guess. I don't use jtls to be honest.